# Why am I getting a list index error when there are certainly items in the list at the specific index?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am working on some Code Signal practice problems in Python 2 and I have been running into the same error a lot. Like the title of the question says, I can not access a specific list element even though i am sure it exists. When I try to run the code shown below I get this error, IndexError: list index out of range. Shown below is some code I am working with. Any help is appreciated, i'm sure this is a simple misunderstanding of how Python2 works. In this example
s = "adobecodebanc" and t is not relevant for my question

```
    def minSubstringWithAllChars(s, t):
        nuS = str(s)
        listS = list(nuS)

        for i in range(len(listS)):
            print i
            print listS[i]

        print listS[0]
```

When I omit the last line of code I am able to print all of the characters that are in S - as shown below. However, when I add the last line, I am unable to print anything as a I get an indexing error.

```
    0
    a
    1
    d
    2
    o
    3
    b
    4
    e
    5
    c
    6
    o
    7
    d
    8
    e
    9
    b
    10
    a
    11
    n
    12
    c
```

What could this be due to? Here is the text of my error message

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            file.py on line ?, in getUserOutputs
              userOutput = _runjodsn(testInputs[i])
            file.py on line ?, in _runjodsn
              return minSubstringWithAllChars(*_fArgs_nycavblqytqu)
            file.py on line 9, in minSubstringWithAllChars
              print listS[0]
          IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you please include the text of your error message (stack trace)?

Comment: No problem. I added it at the bottom of my question

Comment: Instead of printing listS[0], try to `print(listS)` just to see how the list looks like before you try and access it via index.

Comment: It looks just like the list you would expect to see. Here is the what I printed out when i printed the entire list. ['a', 'd', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'c']. This shows that there is an item in the index 0 of listS. So i'm not sure what's going on!

Comment: I think it's the platform you're using. If you see the stacktrace, it's clearly not only executing what you've shown here. There are other intermediate calls and even the arguments to minSubstringWithAllChars are passed as  non-keyworded variable length argument (*_fArgs_nycavblqytqu) and not formal args we're testing here. Also a stacktrace of a Indexerror with that code would produce this stacktrace: `File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    minSubstringWithAllChars("abe", "")
  File "main.py", line 9, in minSubstringWithAllChars
    print listS[7]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running into a strange issue with your provider python compiler or maybe, since it's a page with a web application to test, run and validate python exercices, your code is not running exactly the way you see it on the web page.

This can be clearly spoted if you compare your code to the stacktrace, which has additional calls and even the arguments for your function don't seem to be standard formal arguments, but a *args (non-keyworded variable length argument) argument.

A stacktrace for an IndexError for your code (for example if your string argument was empty, would be):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module> 
    minSubstringWithAllChars("abe", "") 
  File "main.py", line 9, in minSubstringWithAllChars 
    print listS[0] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Anyway, running With python 2.7.13 clearly shows no problem with your code:

```
def minSubstringWithAllChars(s):
    nuS = str(s)
    listS = list(nuS)
    print("working with string: " + nuS)
    print("Len of s: " + str(len(nuS)))
    print("Len of listS: " + str(len(listS)))
    print("\n")

    for i in range(len(listS)):
        print("Checking position: " + str(i) + " of String (" + nuS + "): " + listS[i])

    print("\nAdditional access to listS via index 0: ")
    print listS[0]

print("Start\n")
minSubstringWithAllChars("adobecodebanc")
print("\nEnd")
```

You can see it works:

```
Start

working with string: adobecodebanc
Len of s: 13
Len of listS: 13


Checking position: 0 of String (adobecodebanc): a
Checking position: 1 of String (adobecodebanc): d
Checking position: 2 of String (adobecodebanc): o
Checking position: 3 of String (adobecodebanc): b
Checking position: 4 of String (adobecodebanc): e
Checking position: 5 of String (adobecodebanc): c
Checking position: 6 of String (adobecodebanc): o
Checking position: 7 of String (adobecodebanc): d
Checking position: 8 of String (adobecodebanc): e
Checking position: 9 of String (adobecodebanc): b
Checking position: 10 of String (adobecodebanc): a
Checking position: 11 of String (adobecodebanc): n
Checking position: 12 of String (adobecodebanc): c

Additional access to listS via index 0: 
a

End
```

Another thing is that you don't need to use indexes to iterate your string characters (or break your string into an array of characters with list()). You can just shortcut with this:

```
for i in nuS:
    print i
```

Comment: While I'm not sure this counts as an answer, I agree that the provided code runs without issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I turned the argument of the function into a string and then into a list just to ensure I was dealing with a list and not with a unicode or string. Although when i tried printing the value of s directly (s[0]) it also gave me the same error